# Way to modify rule created by Commerce Fixed amount coupon

Tags: rules, commerce

Currently Fixed amount coupon will be applied to the cart irrespective of number of items present in a cart, I need to modify its rule so that it will be applied to each item present in the cart and total amount deducted should be according to the number of items present. For example- I have Fixed amount coupon "TEST" with amount $100, no. of items in my cart are 3, then total amount deducted after applying coupon should be $300, currently amount deducted is $100.
Anyone can help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After research I found drupal project [link](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_couponprodref), this module will apply percentage coupon to specific products, I will this as a reference and will try to write custom code.